# Null Reference Exception possibly related to cookie expiration in ASP.NET MVC application on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Server Cookie Expire problem in ASP.NET MVC.

We uploaded an ASP.NET MVC project to a server and published it over a domain. When we go live in a project where, we do not encounter any errors locally, but we receive a null reference error. This error sometimes does not occur for 3-4 hours. But then not all users can log in. The error I foresee is that the cookie expires after a while.

Related code:

```
// I am getting when user logged in system
int roleId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ROLE_ID"]);
string userData = $"{roleId}&{email}&{password}"; 
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userData, true);


HttpCookie role = Request.Cookies.Get("roleId");
int roleId = Convert.ToInt32(role.Value.ToString());
```

Entire code:

```
public PartialViewResult NavigationPartial()
{
    List<KategoriModel> MenuKategoriModel = new List<KategoriModel>();

    try
    {
          HttpCookie role = Request.Cookies.Get("roleId");
          int roleId = Convert.ToInt32(role.Value.ToString());

          using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(OracleHelper.DbConnect))
          {
              con.Open();

              //string query = @"SELECT ztpm.MENU_ID , ztpm.MENU_AD , ztpm.PARENT_ID ,ztpm.CONTROLLER_AD ,ztpm.ACTION_AD , ztpm.ACTIVE_FLAG FROM Z_TMP_PORTAL_MENU ztpm START WITH MENU_ID IN (SELECT MENU_ID FROM Z_TMP_PORTAL_MENUROLE_RS ztpmr WHERE ROLE_ID = " + roleId + ") CONNECT BY PRIOR PARENT_ID = MENU_ID"; ;
              string query = @"SELECT MENU_ID,MENU_AD, PARENT_ID, CONTROLLER_AD, MENU_ICON, ACTIVE_FLAG, ACTION_AD FROM ( SELECT MENU_ID,PARENT_ID, CONTROLLER_AD,MENU_AD, MENU_ICON, ACTIVE_FLAG, ACTION_AD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MENU_ID ORDER BY 1) AS rn FROM Z_TMP_PORTAL_MENU ztpm  START WITH MENU_ID IN (SELECT MENU_ID FROM Z_TMP_PORTAL_MENUROLE_RS ztpmr WHERE ROLE_ID = " + roleId + " AND ACTIVE_FLAG='Y' )  CONNECT BY PRIOR PARENT_ID = MENU_ID) WHERE rn = 1";

              using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con))
              {
                  OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                  while (dr.Read())
                  {
                      MenuKategoriModel.Add(new KategoriModel()
                      {
                          MENU_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["MENU_ID"]),
                          MENU_AD = dr["MENU_AD"].ToString(),
                          PARENT_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PARENT_ID"]),
                          CONTROLLER_AD = dr["CONTROLLER_AD"].ToString(),
                          ACTION_AD = dr["ACTION_AD"].ToString(),
                          ACTIVE_FLAG = dr["ACTIVE_FLAG"].ToString(),
                      });
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Logger.LogRegister(ex.Message + " navigation partial kısmı: ", ex.StackTrace, ex.Source);
          return PartialView();
      }

      return PartialView(MenuKategoriModel);
}
```

---

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(string email, string password, string returnUrl)
{
   Session.Timeout = 60;
   ViewBag.login = true;
   ViewBag.WrongInfo = true;

   HttpCookie Cookie = CookieKontrol.CookieGetir();

   if (Cookie != null)
   {
       ViewBag.Cookie = Cookie["Mail"];
   }

   email = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(email);
   password = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(password);

   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
   {
       string encPass = Encrypt(password);
       string DecPass = Decrypt(encPass);

       #region Google
       //var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
       //const string secret = "6LfY43MmAAAAAOISDc7QuFWN_j_M_XaNxlvIJfjC";
       //var client = new WebClient();
       //var reply =
       //    client.DownloadString(
       //        string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", secret, response));
       //var captchaResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CaptchaResponse>(reply);
       //if (!captchaResponse.Success)
       //{
       //    TempData["Message"] = "Lütfen Robot olmadığınızı ispatlayınız!";
       //    ViewBag.WrongInfo = true;
       //}
       //else
       //{
       #endregion

       try
       {
           using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(OracleHelper.DbConnect))
           {
               con.Open();
               //USER_ID
               string query = @"SELECT ROLE_ID,PWD_EXPIRE_DATE FROM Z_TMP_PORTAL_USER ztpu INNER JOIN Z_TMP_PORTAL_USER_ROLE ztpur ON ztpu.USER_ID = ztpur.USER_ID WHERE " +
               "USER_NAME = :prm_UserName AND USER_PASS = :prm_PassWord";

               using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con))
               {
                   cmd.Parameters.Add(":prm_UserName", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = email;
                   cmd.Parameters.Add(":prm_PassWord", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = password;
                   using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                   {
                       // Else if ,if,else kullanılacak flag işlemi için
                       if (dr.Read()) //Bu kısımda boolen değeri false dönüyor
                       {
                           int roleId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ROLE_ID"]);
                           ExpiredDate = (dr["PWD_EXPIRE_DATE"] == DBNull.Value || dr["PWD_EXPIRE_DATE"] == null) ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(dr["PWD_EXPIRE_DATE"]);
                           //ExpiredDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                           CookieKontrol.CookieKaydet(email);
                           HttpCookie role = new HttpCookie("roleId", roleId.ToString());
                           Response.Cookies.Add(role);
                           //role.HttpOnly = true;
                           //role.Secure = true;
                           string userData = $"{roleId}&{email}&{password}"; //TODO : bu yöntemle değil şifre değiştirme ekranında db den sorgu ile çekerek güvenlik için şifre değiştir.
                           FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userData, true);

                           if (ExpiredDate == DateTime.MinValue)
                           {
                               return RedirectToAction("CreateNewPassword", "Login");
                           }

                           if (DateTime.Now > ExpiredDate)
                           {
                               return RedirectToAction("CreateNewPassword", "Login");
                           }
                           con.Close();
                           dr.Close();
                           return Redirect(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? returnUrl : Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
                       }

                       else
                       {
                           //Logger.LogUserControl(email, password);
                           ViewBag.WrongInfo = true;
                           TempData["Message"] = "Hatalı E-mail veya şifre! Lütfen tekrar deneyin.";
                           con.Close();
                           dr.Close();

                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Logger.LogRegister(ex.Message + " Login index post kısmı - ReturnURL: " +returnUrl, ex.StackTrace, ex.Source);
           return RedirectToAction("IslemSırasındaHata", "PageError");
       }
   }

   return View();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please tell me you are **not** persisting clear text passwords ...